# why the remote git repo did not change the folder name to lowercase

Tags: git, github

I have a local folder named `Pictures` in repo，after I rename the folder to the lowercase `pictures`, the remote repo folder name still `Pictures`. I have tried this command:

```
$ git mv Pictures pictures
fatal: renaming 'Pictures' failed: Invalid argument
```

did not work. What should I do to let the remote github [repo](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/interview-question) folder name move to the lowercase? I have rename the folder `pictures` to uppercase and using this command by add force:

```
$ git mv Pictures pictures --force
fatal: renaming 'Pictures' failed: Invalid argument
```

still did not work. my OS is macOS Monetey 12.3.1 with arm chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using :

1)

```
run this in bash git config --global core.ignorecase false 
     -f
    --force
```

Force renaming or moving of a file even if the target exists

Or If this doesn't work

2)

```
git mv Pictures pictures1
git mv pictures1 pictures
```

**It is 2 step process**

Comment: still this error.@leoz

Comment: run this in bash git config --global core.ignorecase false

Comment: try using

git mv Pictures pictures1
git mv pictures1 pictures

Comment: `git config --global core.ignorecase false` works.